# MySql select list of data as array inside SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on an e-commerce like project where I need to get data from a relational database. With the main data I also need to get other type of data to store as an array inside the main data. For example, when I select the information about an order, I'll get the main data from this table:

```
order
id | id_payment | id_status | date | value | discount |...
```

This will return an object for me. Then I'll get the list of products related to this order from the table `order_products`, for example:

```
order_products
id | id_order | name | description | value | ...
```

After I get this information I'll send to the frontend as json, something like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    date: 2017-01-22,
    value: 27.90,
    products: [
        {id: 18, name: 'shoes', description...},
        {id: 23, name: 'dress', description...}
        {id: 41, name: 'Tie', description...}
    ]
}
```

When I want to get this extra information to store as an array/object inside the main data, I'm using queries like this:

```
$order = get("SELECT id, date, value FROM order WHERE id = :id");

$order['products'] = get("SELECT id, name, description FROM order_products WHERE id_order = :id");
$order['payment'] = get("SELECT id, name, icon, label FROM payment WHERE....")[0];
```

So, for each `array/object` I want to insert into the main data I'm doing an extra `SELECT`. Is there a way to move all of this into the main SELECT? Or the way I'm doing is the best/only way to do this to achieve this objective?

Comment: The way you chose is seems logical and correct. This topic is one of the main ideas behind Object Relational Mapping. You may reduce query count by using JOIN (joining payment and order details is logical) and to do that you should assign unique names for each fields. if i were in your shoes I would leave it that way or use an ORM.

Comment: @TuğcaEker What do you mean by ORM? I'm starting learning backend process now.

Comment: in my limited view, i think you can do two different queries, inserting the second one into the result of the first one.